# how to query for min or max inet/cidr with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-9.4

Consider query:

```
select min(d) from temp;
select max(d) from temp;
```

Either one, I get an error like:

```
# select max(d) from temp;
ERROR:  function max(inet) does not exist
LINE 1: select max(d) from temp;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So, I create a table called temp and populate it:

```
create table temp (d inet);
insert into temp (d) values ('1.1.10.2');
insert into temp (d) values ('1.1.10.10');
insert into temp (d) values ('1.1.10.20');
insert into temp (d) values ('1.1.10.100');

# select * from temp order by d;

     d      
------------
 1.1.10.2
 1.1.10.10
 1.1.10.20
 1.1.10.100
(4 rows)
```

So, I can use host() to convert to text, but that produces incorrect answer:

```
select min(host(d)) from temp;
```

That is because it is doing a text 'min' function, which is this ordering:

```
# select host(d) as r from temp order by r;
     r      
------------
 1.1.10.10
 1.1.10.100
 1.1.10.2
 1.1.10.20
(4 rows)
```

Is there a min() and max() function for ip types in postgres?  There are ways to trick it (convert to int and compare, or do a order by with a limit).  I am more interested in proper min() and max().  Thank you SO!

-g

Comment: i read this http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAJrrPGdeZpfTPR6EkGgM6A4bUG7BVVToXsMgqJ6rg7R1JRUPVg@mail.gmail.com and i think there is already a patch fixed this. but i tried on PG9.3 it failed, my friend tried on 9.4 it failed too.i think what you can do is mapping it into int and use min() on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existing functions `network_smaller(inet, inet)` and `network_larger(inet, inet)` to define your own aggregates:

```
create aggregate min (inet) (
    sfunc = network_smaller,
    stype = inet);

create aggregate max (inet) (
    sfunc = network_larger,
    stype = inet);

select min(d) min, max(d) max
from temp;

   min    |    max     
----------+------------
 1.1.10.2 | 1.1.10.100
(1 row)
```

Comment: thank you!  I am aware of this sort of work around.  I had just read that min() and max() exist after 9.3, but I just can't find them.  I was hoping for an answer that will tell me how I can use min() and max().

Comment: I've found a better solution, see the edited answer.

Comment: Is this really not what you were looking for? The solution is as close as possible to the core of Postgres.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I really thought I was overlooking something that was/should be in postgres itself. I guess  you did answer my question: min() and max() aren't available for inet types. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

i checked again, pg still not support min(inet). i guess what you can do is make another column to mapping the inet like replace(r,'.','') and min() it.

Comment: This will not work with IPs like 0.1.0.1 . You definitely need the value representation of that ip.