# Get MAX and MIN ip from subnet/mask in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following issue:

Right now I have a table with the subnet/mask information (example 192.168.1.0 / 255.255.255.0 ) .. but I need to obtain the MAX and MIN IP from this subnet:

192.168.1.0 / 192.168.1.255

I've found this answer:

[how to query for min or max inet/cidr with postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144057/how-to-query-for-min-or-max-inet-cidr-with-postgres)

But it seems that:

**network_smaller(inet, inet)** and **network_larger(inet, inet)**

Doesn't exists. Even googling that I can't find any answer for those functions.

Thanks!

Edit:

**Version info:**

PostgreSQL 9.2.15 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4), 64-bit

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that question is relavent to your needs anyway.  The min and max defined there are similar to the SQL `min()` and `max()` functions for finding the smallest / largest in a table, not the smallest / largest in a subnet.

I'm not generally a fan of relying on undocumented features. They *may* be safe but *may* isn't a word I generally like.

There's a page of documented network functions here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html

The two you would need would be:

- Min would be `network(inet)`
- Max would be `broadcast(inet)`

That's because the network name is always the "first" ip in the range and the broadcast address is always the "last" ip in the range.

Answer (score 0):

Don't google, just try:

```
select network_smaller('192.168.0.9'::inet, '192.168.0.11'::inet);

 network_smaller 
-----------------
 192.168.0.9
(1 row)
```

Postgres has more than 2,600 internal functions. Most of them are useful for creating operator classes of various types. Not all of them are described in the documentation, but they are all generally available.

You can find them using pgAdmin III in pg_catalog. You only need to set the option: File -> Options -> UI Miscellaneous -> Show System Objects in treeview.

---

The aggregate functions `min(inet)` and `max(inet)` has been introduced in **Postgres 9.5**:

```
with test(ip) as (
values 
    ('192.168.0.123'::inet),
    ('192.168.0.12'),
    ('192.168.0.1'),
    ('192.168.0.125')   
)
select max(ip), min(ip)
from test;

      max      |     min     
---------------+-------------
 192.168.0.125 | 192.168.0.1
(1 row)
```

See how the aggregate `min(inet)` is defined (it can be found in `pg_catalog`):

```
CREATE AGGREGATE min(inet) (
  SFUNC=network_smaller,
  STYPE=inet,
  SORTOP="<"
);
```

The question [How to query for min or max inet/cidr with postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35144331/1995738) concerned **Postgres 9.4**. In my answer I suggested to use the functions `network_smaller(inet, inet)` and `network_larger(inet, inet)`. I'm sure they were added for creating aggregate functions `min(inet)` and `max(inet)` but for some reasons (maybe oversight) the aggregates appeared only in Postgres 9.5.

In **Postgres 9.2** you can create your own functions as substitutes, e.g.

```
create or replace function inet_larger(inet, inet)
returns inet language sql as $$
    select case when network_gt($1, $2) then $1 else $2 end
$$;

create or replace function inet_smaller(inet, inet)
returns inet language sql as $$
    select case when network_lt($1, $2) then $1 else $2 end
$$;
```

Comment: Well. I've obviously tried that..

ERROR: function network_smaller(inet, inet) does not exist
  
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Just a question. How safe is it to rely on such an undocumented feature?

Comment: @PhilipCouling - Can we rely on the internal functions? I think so, as far as all operators, indexes, sorting and most aggregates are based on them.